# NodeJS ETIMEDOUT2

Tags: node.js, tcp

My sockets keep on erroring out with ETIMEDOUT2. I know what ETIMEDOUT means, but I have never heard of ETIMEDOUT2.

From reading the NodeJS documentation I thought [this list](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) was a comprehensive list of system error messages.

I have also checked out the `libuv` repository and its documentation, but no sign of this error message.

I've searched the NodeJS repo for the error and googled as well, but no one else seems to have ever encountered the message either.

This is on an Ubuntu system.

Sample log:

```
[DATE] [ERROR] connection - { message: 'socket error',
uidx: XXXX,
dest_id: 'XXXXX',
error: 'ETIMEDOUT2' }
```

Comment: You sure it is coming from NodeJS? I can't find it even in Node's source code!

Comment: Grepping the source code of my project and modules found nothing.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Can you post it if you do?

Comment: Sadly no stacktrace :/ this is being logged without that. Le Groan.

Comment: Well then I guess node-debug is your best friend :-). I guess find out at which point in your code it's getting thrown and then maybe drill down.